# Ionic - The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an Ionic app using Angular and Firebase.

For the past couple months I've been testing on android by running:

```
ionic cordova run android --device --prod
```

This has worked great for me in the past. Recently, though, I've been getting an error which I can't seem to fix:

```
:app:preDebugBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.1,11.0.1], [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

My `build.gradle` file located in `platforms\android\app` has the following dependencies... I'm not sure if this is the correct `build.gradle`..

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Is there any explanation for this? What can I do to fix? Thank you!

Comment: jane doe   please run this './gradlew :app:dependencies' in your terminal and show me the out put in the question

Comment: @Rizwanatta thanks for the comment, I get `bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory`... i do have gradle installed. When I do `gradle -v` I get `Gradle 4.9`...

Comment: in ionic you are not bound to go and manually change dependencies in the app's build.gradle!.... make sure you are in the ionic project's directory while running the gradlw command ! it is bound to be there!

Comment: @Rizwanatta I ran it in the main directory of the project...